SharepointList to Azure synapse
I am trying to create a copy activity in Azure synapse analytics that copies data from a SharePoint List. I already have an APP registered and a linked service created. My issue is that once the data is copied over I am not able to see all the columns from my SharePoint List, mostly the complex columns types (choice, lookup, yes/no). Does anybody have a workaround?
Thanks

As per the Documentation,

For lookup data type in the source you need to give int32 as target data type and for Yes/No, give Boolean data type. There is no complex data type in the documentation. So, you can set the complex data type to string.

Do the above in the copy activity mapping. You can also edit the pipeline JSON to edit the mapping.


Does anybody have a workaround?

You can try logic app as a workaround if you still face issue with ADF. In logic app connect to SharePoint and first list the files in the folder using Get files action and then use Get file content using path action to get the file content. Then you can use your target action to copy this file content to your target. If your files are more, then use a loop with these actions.
You can go through this Ask by @Mike Urnun to learn more about this approach.
